# Only send PHPSESSID in Angular 2

Tags: php, angularjs, angular

Is it possible to send only the PHPSESSID when I request my api? I ask this because in the request I make (attached image) I send the cookie auth and I do not need to send it.

[image: Request]

Request code

```
  this.token = this.cookies.getCookie("auth");

  let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'text/html', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token});
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, body: '', withCredentials: true});    
  return this.http.get(this.urlbase + "pesquisa/"+pesquisa+"/"+pag , options)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json());
```

Comment: Did you try? What do you get?

Comment: I searched but did not find anything so I decided to ask

Comment: Why not just try it?

Comment: I'd even try if I knew how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are asking and what the problem is...